# Creating a record to laravel databse with vue.js doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to create a new record to my database using Vue.js in laravel, my API, data is okay. But I get that strange error when I click create on my site.

**Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Productivity\gitdemo\students\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 884**

I also have delete function that works perfectly, but this doesn't work... Form inputs have `v-model`, that seems alright, but it still doesn't work.

**My create method on vue.js**

```
addStudent() {
                axios.post(`api/students/create`, {data:this.students});
            }
```

**Getting records in vue.js**

```
data() {
            return{
                students: [],
            }
        },

        created() {
            axios.get(`api/students`).then(response =>{
                this.students = response.data.data;
            })
        },
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Student::create($request->all());

        return view('welcome');
    }
```

**Route (in api.php)**

```
Route::post('students/create', 'StudentController@store');
```

**Student Model**

```
use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['birth_date'];
    
    protected $guarded = [];
```

Students array in data has all of the `v-model` namings

Comment: show me your backend code.

Comment: you mean controller?

Comment: I've updated the question @AhmadMobaraki

Comment: Show me the student model please

Comment: Try like this, only return Student ```return Student:create($request->all());```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please mark the answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not directly pass `$request->all()` to create method. Based on what you send from front end to back end, do this:

```
$r = $request->all();
$students = $r['data'];
Student:create($students);
```